# Operations with big COMPLEX numbers in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I wrote a `simply Fortran` code that uses a Bessel function subroutine to solve a fluid-structure interaction problem. the bessel function found are 8-dimensional vector of `complex*16` type. The first four elements of the found vectors give NAN and for the last four elements give fair values. the same code is written under `intel fortran` and it gives all the numerical values of the components of the bessel function vector.

```
INTEGER N, NP1, IER
DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER :: EPS = 10.0D-12
COMPLEX*16 :: AUX, AUX2, AUX3
COMPLEX*16 :: VECT_AUX(8), VECT_AUX2(8), VECT_AUX3(8), RQ(8), LAMDAS(8)
```

```
   CALL BESSJ(AUX,N,AUX2,EPS,IER)
   VECT_AUX2(JK)=AUX2  
   CALL BESSJ(AUX,NP1,AUX3,EPS,IER)
   VECT_AUX3(JK)=AUX3
   RQ(JK)=1.0/(PN-AUX*(AUX3/AUX2))  ! SOLUTION OF BEESEL FUNCTION
```

The results given using simply fortran:

```
 !====== VECT_AUX ======
 ( -52.078796118420847     ,  62.859646088924379     )
 ( -52.078796118420847     , -62.859646088924379     )
 (  52.078796118420847     ,  62.859646088924379     )
 (  52.078796118420847     , -62.859646088924379     )
 ( -4.8816792606421169     ,  5.8903897259013362     )
 ( -4.8816792606421169     , -5.8903897259013362     )
 (  4.8816792606421169     ,  5.8903897259013362     )
 (  4.8816792606421169     , -5.8903897259013362     )
 !====== VECT_AUX2 ======
 (                      NaN,                      NaN)
 (                      NaN,                      NaN)
 (                      NaN,                      NaN)
 (                      NaN,                      NaN)
 (  2.2275304232763871E-011,  1.4362161577399207E-011)
 (  2.2275304232763871E-011, -1.4362161577399207E-011)
 ( -2.2275304232763871E-011,  1.4362161577399207E-011)
 ( -2.2275304232763871E-011, -1.4362161577399207E-011)
 !====== VECT_AUX3 ======
 (                      NaN,                      NaN)
 (                      NaN,                      NaN)
 (                      NaN,                      NaN)
 (                      NaN,                      NaN)
 ( -3.6772018789810943E-012,  1.2444292792182487E-012)
 ( -3.6772018789810943E-012, -1.2444292792182487E-012)
 ( -3.6772018789810943E-012, -1.2444292792182487E-012)
 ( -3.6772018789810943E-012,  1.2444292792182487E-012)
 ! ============ RQ ============
 (                      NaN,                      NaN)
 (                      NaN,                      NaN)
 (                      NaN,                      NaN)
 (                      NaN,                      NaN)
 ( 0.18338870108203947     ,-0.87337225864044421     )
 ( 0.18338870108203947     , 0.87337225864044421     )
 ( 0.18338870108203947     , 0.87337225864044421     )
 ( 0.18338870108203947     ,-0.87337225864044421     )
```

whereas with intel fortran i get

```
 ! ====== VECT_AUX ======
-.520788E+02  0.628596E+02
-.520788E+02  -.628596E+02
0.520788E+02  0.628596E+02
0.520788E+02  -.628596E+02
-.488168E+01  0.589039E+01
-.488168E+01  -.589039E+01
0.488168E+01  0.589039E+01
0.488168E+01  -.589039E+01
! ====== VECT_AUX2 ======
0.313633E+25  -.327621E+25
0.313633E+25  0.327621E+25
-.313633E+25  -.327621E+25
-.313633E+25  0.327621E+25
0.222753E-10  0.143622E-10
0.222753E-10  -.143622E-10
-.222753E-10  0.143622E-10
-.222753E-10  -.143622E-10
! ====== VECT_AUX3 ======
0.203881E+25  0.291338E+25
0.203881E+25  -.291338E+25
0.203881E+25  -.291338E+25
0.203881E+25  0.291338E+25
-.367720E-11  0.124443E-11
-.367720E-11  -.124443E-11
-.367720E-11  -.124443E-11
-.367720E-11  0.124443E-11
! ============ RQ ============
0.969849E-02  -.737084E-02
0.969849E-02  0.737084E-02
0.969849E-02  0.737084E-02
0.969849E-02  -.737084E-02
0.395602E-01  -.171949E-02
0.395602E-01  0.171949E-02
0.395602E-01  0.171949E-02
0.395602E-01  -.171949E-02
```

I wonder why with simply fortran I could not get the same results for the first four components of the bessel vector.

```
PROGRAM BESSEL

INTEGER    :: N, NP1, IER, JK
DOUBLE PRECISION, PARAMETER :: EPS = 10.0D-12
REAL*8     :: DENSITYI 
COMPLEX*16 :: COMPI, AUX, AUX2, AUX3
COMPLEX*16 :: VECT_AUX(8), VECT_AUX2(8), VECT_AUX3(8), RQ(8), LAMDAS(8)

 N = 25
 NP1 = N + 1
 COMPI = (0.0D0,1.0D0)
 DENSITYI = 0.100000E+04 ! INPUT

 LAMDAS(1) = (  62.859646088924379     ,  52.078796118420847     )
 LAMDAS(2) = ( -62.859646088924379     ,  52.078796118420847     )
 LAMDAS(3) = (  62.859646088924379     , -52.078796118420847     )
 LAMDAS(4) = ( -62.859646088924379     , -52.078796118420847     )
 LAMDAS(5) = (  5.8903897259013362     ,  4.8816792606421169     )
 LAMDAS(6) = ( -5.8903897259013362     ,  4.8816792606421169     )
 LAMDAS(7) = (  5.8903897259013362     , -4.8816792606421169     )
 LAMDAS(8) = ( -5.8903897259013362     , -4.8816792606421169     )


 DO 2000 JK=1,8                                                              
      AUX= LAMDAS(JK)*COMPI 
      VECT_AUX(JK)=AUX 
      IF(DENSITYI.NE.0.0) GO TO 2010                                             
      RQ(JK)=(0.0,0.0)                                                           
      GO TO 2000                                                                       

 2010 CALL BESSJ(AUX,N,AUX2,EPS,IER)                
           VECT_AUX2(JK)=AUX2
      CALL BESSJ(AUX,NP1,AUX3,EPS,IER)              
           VECT_AUX3(JK)=AUX3
      RQ(JK)=1.0/(N-AUX*(AUX3/AUX2))  ! SOLUTION OF BEESEL FUNCTION

 2000  CONTINUE

PRINT*,'======= VECT_AUX ======'
DO JK=1,8
PRINT*, VECT_AUX(JK)
END DO

PRINT*,'======= VECT_AUX2 ======'
DO JK=1,8
PRINT*, VECT_AUX2(JK)
END DO

PRINT*,'======= VECT_AUX3 ======'
DO JK=1,8
PRINT*, VECT_AUX3(JK)
END DO

PRINT*,'======= RQ ======'
DO JK=1,8
PRINT*, RQ(JK)
END DO

END PROGRAM BESSEL
```

```
!************************************************************************
SUBROUTINE BESSJ  (Z,N,BJ,EPS,IER)                                        
!  BUT =   CALCULER LA FONCTION BESSEL J(Z)                                     
!  USAGE = CALL BESSJ  (Z,N,BJ,EPS,IER)                                         
!  PARAMETRES                                                                   
!          Z = ARGUMENT (COMPLEXE)                                              
!          N = ORDRE DEMANDE. FAUT N GE 0                                       
!          BJ= LE RESULTAT DE LA FONCTION BESSEL J                              
!          EPS=PRECISION DEMANDEE, LE CALCUL SE TERMINE LORSQUE L"ERREUR        
!              RELATIVE EPS A ETE ATTEINTE.                                     
!          IER=CODE D"ERREUR                                                    
!                  =0  CORRECT                                                  
!                  =1  N LT 0                                                   
!                  =3  PRECISION NON ATTEINTE                                   
!                                                                               
!                                                                               
!***********************************************************************        
      IMPLICIT REAL*8(A-H,O-Z)
      COMPLEX*16 Z, BJ, BJ1                                                        
!                                                                               
                                                   
!                                                                               
      BJ=(0.0,0.0)                                                              
      IER=0                                                                     
      IF(N) 10,100,100                                                          
10    IER=1                                                                     
      RETURN                                                                    
100   IF(DREAL(Z))200,50,200                                                     
!        Z=(0.0,0.0)                                                            
50    IF(N.EQ.0) BJ=(1.0,0.0)                                                   
      RETURN                                                                    
!        CALCUL PAR LA METHODE DES SERIES ASCENDANTES                           
!                                                                               
200   DO 55 KK=1,99                                                             
      K=KK-1                                                                    
      XX=DFLOAT(N+K+1)                                                           
      BJ= BJ+(((-0.25*Z**2)**K) /(AGAMMA(DFLOAT(KK))*AGAMMA(XX)))   
               
      IF(KK-10)55,9,90                                                          
90    AUX=(CDABS(BJ)-CDABS(BJ1))/CDABS(BJ1)                                        
      IF(DABS(AUX).LE.EPS) GO TO 25                                              
9     BJ1=BJ                                                                    
55    CONTINUE                                                                  
!        PRECISION NON ATTEINTE CODE ERREUR 3                                   
      IER=3                                                                     
      RETURN                                                                    
25    BJ= ((0.5*Z)**N)*BJ                                                       
      RETURN                                                                    
      END
```

In fact, this part is extracted from a long program, which consists in determining the BESSEL functions to study the dynamic behaviour of structures when they are subjected to a potential flow.

```
 FUNCTION   AGAMMA(XX)  
!     ---------------------

!     COMPUTES THE GAMMA FUNCTION FOR A GIVEN ARGUMENT                          
!     XX=THE ARGUMENT FOR THE GAMMA FUNCTION.                    
!                                                                               
!                                                                               
    IMPLICIT REAL*8(A-H,O-Z)
    REAL (KIND=8):: AGAMMA  !ADDED BY FARHAD FOR QUAD PERCISION
      IF(XX-100.0)6,6,4                                                         
    4 IER=2                                                                     
      AGAMMA=9.33262E155_8  !IT IS MODIFIED BY FARHAD   
    RETURN                                                                    
    6 X=XX                                                                      
      ERR=1.0D-6                                                                
      IER=0                                                                     
      AGAMMA=1.0     
      IF(X-2.0)50,50,15                                                         
   10 IF(X-2.0)110,110,15                                                       
   15 X=X-1.0                                                                   
      AGAMMA=AGAMMA*X  
    GO TO 10                                                                  
   50 IF(X-1.0)60,120,110                                                       
!                                                                               
!     SEE IF X IS NEAR NEGATIVE INTEGER OR ZERO                                 
!                                                                               
   60 IF(X-ERR)62,62,80                                                         
   62 Y=DFLOAT(INT(X))-X                                                         
      IF(DABS(Y)-ERR)130,130,64                                                  
   64 IF(1.0-Y-ERR)130,130,70                                                   
!                                                                               
!     X NOT NEAR A NEGATIVE INTEGER OR ZERO                                     
!                                                                               
   70 IF(X-1.0)80,80,110                                                        
   80 AGAMMA=AGAMMA/X      
      X=X+1.0                                                                   
      GO TO 70                                                                  
  110 Y=X-1.0                                                                   
      GY= 1.0+Y*(-0.5771017+Y*(0.9858540+Y*(-0.8764218+Y*(0.8328212+ &           
      Y*(-0.5684729+Y*(0.2548205+Y*(-0.05149930)))))))                          
       AGAMMA=AGAMMA*GY 
    
  120 RETURN                                                                    
  130 IER=1                                                                     
      RETURN                                                                    
      END
```

Comment: Welcome, please use tag [tag:fortran] and show us more code. See [mcve] and [ask]. We should be able to reproduce your results.

Comment: Simply Fortran use gfortran for its compiler.  Add the debugging options: "-fcheck=all -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero" to your options.

Comment: Note that only numbers with large powers (XX E+25) that are replaced by NAN with gfortran, is this can be related to the complier?

Comment: Other numbers are changed too. Show us more code and the input data, otherwise no-one can tell you what happens.

Comment: We need to see actual code.  I'm guessing that you are using an uninitialized variable.

Comment: Only these numbers which have been changed.

Comment: II am getting the exact same results for Intel and for gfortran. Please specify 1. the exact versions of your compilers, 2. the exact compilation commands you use.

Comment: Running with gfortran 11.2,  `bessj` is not converging. It is returning `ier=3`, i.e. "precision non atteinte". Along the way, this generates your `NaN`s.

Comment: I use gnu fortran 6.3.0 (version 2.36) and Microsoft visual studio ultimate 2012. I also tried with `BESSEL_JN(N1, N2, X)` for gfortran but it doesn't work.

Comment: Tell us also your Intel Fortran version and the exact command you use, Visual Studio is not a compiler, we need details about the Intel Compiler, not about Microsoft Studio. My Intel Fortran 2022 diverges in the same way as gfortran. The results are identical for both compilers. Also, never say  "it doesn't work". Say what exactly happens. BESSEL_JN does work, but you are probably using it incorrectly. You can open a new question about that, but you must show details.